# Number guesser game

Tags: python, python-2.x, number-guessing-game

```
def guessr():
    '''Application that generates 5 numbers which a user enters a number as a guess to match any of the number generated
    by the application, if you is able to guess one of the numbers correct, user has won, else user lost'''

    from random import randint

    print 'Welcome to the Number Guesser Application'
    print 'You are required to enter a number between 1 to 20'
    print 'You would be rewarded for a correct answer guessed right'


    end_game = False
    computer_guess = []

    # Generate a list of 5 unique numbers
    for x in range(0, 5):
        computer_guess.append(randint(1, 20))

    # Check if user guess with an integer, if you entered some more than an integer, immediatelly end game
    try:
        while not end_game:
            # User gusess
            user_guess = int(raw_input('Enter your guess: '))
            # Guess can not be less than 0 and more than 20
            if user_guess > 20:
                print 'Your guess can not be greater than 20'
            elif user_guess < 1:
                print 'Your guess can not be less than 1'
            elif user_guess in computer_guess:
                print 'Your got it right. {} was in the list of guesses.'.format(user_guess)
                # Finally end game
                end_game = True
            else:
                print 'Please try again.'
    except ValueError:
        print 'To guess you must enter a number'
        # Testing the new line break in my code
        print 'Invalid characters are not allowed.\nGood Bye!!!' 
        # print 'Good Bye!!!' 

def main():
    guessr()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Comparing this to the previous scripts i posted.

Comment: Your post is a little empty right now. I think you could improve its quality if you added some more information to it, like what you would like reviewed.

Answer (score 3):

- A `main()` function is not *required* in Python - so why do you have a `main()` function *and* `guessr()` function if all `main()` does is call `guessr()`? You can just remove the main() function and do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    guessr()
```

which calls the `guessr()` function

- If you want to make the game harder, you could use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample). This will create the random numbers **without duplicates**. It also removes your for loop, so you could simply do:

```
computer_guess = random.sample(xrange(1, 20), 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put imports inside a function, put them at the very top of the file before you run any other code. There's no reason to put the import inside the function. Even if this function is being imported to another script, the import will run this import from random for you so you wont have issues.

Instead of using

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    computer_guess.append(randint(1, 20))
```

You could just use a list comprehension:

```
computer_guess = [randint(1, 20) for _ in range(5)]
```

You don't need to pass 0 as the starting value, that's the default. Also it's idiomatic to use `_` for the name of an unused value in Python.

Also you could just put the `ValueError` directly around the user input and not break the game. Just point out that their input wasn't valid and then let the loop run again.